# logback logs not getting exported to datadog by opentelemetry-collector

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth, open-telemetry

I have created a spring-boot application with open-telemetry. I have used spring-cloud-sleuth for exporting the traces to a open-telemetry collectors which ultimately is exporting these traces to datadog. I can see the exported traces in the datadog.
Now, I also have to add some logging to the application and open-telemetry does not support logging directly. So, I have used opentelemetry-logback-appender to export the logs also to  datadog. I can see the log has same trace id and span id as the exported traces in the console. However, the logs are not getting forwarded to datadog.
My code :-

otel-collector-config.yaml :-

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:

processors:
  batch:

exporters:
  datadog:
    api:
      site: datadoghq.com
      key: ${DD_API_KEY}
  file:
    path: /tmp/signals.json
  logging:
    loglevel: debug

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [datadog, logging, file]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [datadog, logging, file]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging, file]
```

Log in the console added with slf4j (logback):

```
spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-slf4j-spring-cloud-sleuth-otel-slf4j-1  | 09:25:45.835 [http-nio-8181-exec-1] ERROR com.uplight.web.MyController traceId: c9c54856c474a11e22e3716b6e97ec4b spanId: 569063cd0411d3a6 - Logging error using SLF4J LOGGER--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

As seen in image, the log is not available in the trace. Can someone please suggest if I am missing anything?

Comment: you missed the exporter in the logs pipeline.

Comment: I have already tried adding it...but I get an error that it is not supported

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a version of the collector less than 0.61.0, which [added logs support for the datadogexporter (#2651)](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/releases/tag/v0.61.0), then if you update your collector and add datadog to the logs pipeline, logs should appear in Datadog.

Comment: You know about the commenting privilege which you do not have, so well that you can even put it into words. You are aware of the rule https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead . In that situation please do not decide to misuse a different mechanism (an answer) for something it is not meant for and which you are not allowed yet to do.

Comment: So please [edit] to make the part which is an answer according to [answer] more obvious, because I think there is one inside.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."